# How to represent A depends on B while B doesn't depend on A?

Tags: probability

Both A and B vote, and A is a follower of B. A copies B's vote results with 90% probability, and votes a random one with 10% probability.

P(final_votes) depends on P(A) and P(B). P(A) depends on P(B), but P(B) doesn't depend on P(A).

If A and B are independent, P(A) shouldn't depend on P(B). If A and B are dependent, P(B) should depend on P(A).

---

Oh, I think even though B's thinking doesn't depend on A. But their voting results are relevant.

Comment: So what is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These random variables are *dependent* -- there is a distinction between the mathematical language here and everyday English. Dependence in probability is not the same thing as causality. Person B's vote depends on person A's in the sense of probability because knowing person As vote would help an observer guess what person Bs vote was. This is true even though in casual English we would not say that Person B's vote depends on person A's.